# jquery dropdown auto-submitting for all options except one

Tags: jquery

```
$(function () {
        $("#dropdown").live("change keyup", function () {
            $("#theform").submit();
        });
    });

<form method="GET" id="theform" action="">
            <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3" id="nosubmit">Three</option>
            </select>
        </form>
```

If option three is selected, I want to reveal another dropdown (without submitting the form):

```
<form method="GET" id="theform2" action="">
            <select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
                <option value="4">Four</option>
                <option value="5">Five</option>
                <option value="6">Six</option>
            </select>
        </form>
```

What would I have to do to NOT have it auto submit if one particular option is selected? Also when that option is selected how would I know? I need to reveal another dropdown in that case.

Comment: FYI, `.live()` is deprecated - check out `.delegate()` or `.on()`, depending on your version of jQuery.

Comment: Tried to do the same with on() but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jQuery that watches for events, you just have to do a little checking before you go forward with submit().

```
$(function () {
    $("#dropdown").live("change keyup", function () {
        if($(this).val() != 3)
        {
            $("#theform").submit();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#dropdown2").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Please note that you shouldn't put the #dropdown2 select into it's own form, unless you only want to submit one set of data or the other.  If you want it all to go together, put it inside a single form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/LYdat/

**HTML**

```
<form method="GET" id="theform" action="">
    <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3" id="nosubmit">Three</option>
    </select>
</form>

<form method="GET" id="theform2" action="">
    <select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
    </select>
</form>​
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $("#dropdown").live("change keyup", function () {
        if($(this).val() == '3') {
            $('#theform2').show();
        } else {
            $('#theform2').hide();
            $("#theform").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

​**CSS**

```
#theform2 {
    display: none;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to do on text i.e "Three"

```
$(function () {
        $("#dropdown").live("change", function () {
            if($("#dropdown :selected").text() == "Three")
            {
                $("#dropdown2").hide();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
               $("#theform").submit();
            }
        });
    });
```

Try this if you want to do on value i.e "3"

```
 $(function () {
        $("#dropdown").live("change", function () { 
            if($(this).val() == "3")      
            {
                $("#dropdown2").hide();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
               $("#theform").submit();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I think you mean to check if the value is 3, not "Three".

Comment: I mean to check "Three" also changed code please check updated

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").on("change keyup", "#dropdown", function () {
            if(this.value == 3) {
               $('#theform2').show();
            } else {
               $('#theform2').hide();
               $("#theform").submit();
            }
});
```

and set css to `#theform2 {display: none}`